# What is the difference between Databricks SQL and Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

What is the difference between Databricks SQL and Spark SQL? Is Data SQL just Spark SQL on Databricks?

Answer (score 5):

Databricks SQL is primarily based on the Spark SQL. And now slowly converging to ANSI SQL syntax (same for Spark SQL).  There are some Databricks-specific extensions in the syntax, like, [CREATE TABLE CLONE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html), or some `ALTER TABLE` variants that are specific to Delta, or VACUUM and OPTIMIZE commands, etc.