# Spark SQL vs Databricks SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I recently started working with spark and was eager to know if I have to perform queries which would be better spark sql or databricks sql and why?

Answer (score 3):

We need to distinguish two things here:

- Spark SQL as a dialect of the SQL language.  Originally started as Shark & Hive on Spark projects ([blog](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2014/07/01/shark-spark-sql-hive-on-spark-and-the-future-of-sql-on-spark.html)), it's now going close to ANSI SQL.
- Spark SQL as execution engine inside Spark.

As was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869606/what-is-the-difference-between-databricks-sql-and-spark-sql/71871130#71871130), Databricks SQL as language is primarily based on Spark SQL with some additions specific to Delta Lake tables (like `CREATE TABLE CLONE`, ...).  ANSI compatibility in Databricks SQL is controlled with [ANSI_MODE setting](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/parameters/ansi_mode.html), and will be enabled by default in the future.

But when it comes to the execution, Databricks SQL is different from Spark SQL engine because it uses [Photon engine](https://www.databricks.com/product/photon) heavily optimized for modern hardware and BI/DW workloads.  With Photon you can get significant speedup (2-3x) compared to standard Spark SQL engine on the complex queries that process a lot of data.

Comment: Do you need to turn on or standardly applied?

Comment: In DBSQL Photon is on by default. On clusters/jobs it may need to be explicitly enabled

Answer (score 0):

In basic nut shell, you can download Apache Spark with pre-built Hadoop. You need to download the package from free. Additionally you can add Delta Lake and other third-party software.
[image]

Now Databricks is platform where you have to pay, it contains Apache SPARK + Delta Lake + many built in extras.
[image]

As expected, performance and SQL dialect between Hadoop and Delta Lake are different since they are different databases.

You can install [Delta Lake](https://delta.io/) in Apache Spark so you compare Hadoop vs Delta Lake